# Disappearing object options window

Tags: modeling

When I create a new object and I go to the options window that pops up to modify the object in the bottom left of the screen, the window completely disappears the moment I left click on any value in that window to change it.

It used to work fine. I have restarted both program and computer.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. As soon as I use F9 to bring it back, I left click on it and it disappears again. I ended up restoring all the default preferences in blender and that seemed to fix it. But, it seemed like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try F9 to get this window back, this can be done before another command